# Calculating the Probability of Winning 40 Points in a Ball Drawing Game

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, random-variables, binomial-distribution

I'm new to probability theory. I'm trying to do some exercices as the one suggested below but I've come across a solution that I didn't quite understand. Can you, guys, help me figure this out?

> A bag contains 2n balls ($n\neq 0$), of which n are white and n are black.
> All the balls are indistinguishable by touch.
>
> A game consists of drawing a ball from the bag, noting its color, and putting it back in the bag, then drawing another ball from the same bag and noting its color as well.
>
> The rules of the game are as follows:
>
> - If both balls drawn are white, you win 20 points (+).
> - If both balls drawn are black, you lose 20 points (-).
> - If the two balls drawn are of different colors, the gain is zero (0).
>
> The game is repeated 5 times.
>
> Calculate the probability of winning 40 points.

I went like this:

Let $A$ be the event of obtaining 2 white balls, $B$ obtaining 2 black balls, $C$ obtaining 2 different colors and $E$ winning 40 points at the end.

We have: $P(A)=P(B)=\frac{1}{4}$ and $P(C)=\frac{1}{2}$.

There is two possible cases of gaining 40 points: (+ + 0 0 0) and ( + + + - 0) with all of the different combinations of those two cases. So,
$$P = C^2_5 P(A)^2 P(C)^3 + \cfrac{5!}{3!1!1!} P(A)^3 P(C) P(B)$$

However, the solution suggested was assigning a random variable $X$ that is equal to the number of times of gaining 20 points needed to gain $k$ points. They said that this random variable follows a binomial distribution $\mathcal{B}(5,P(A))$. Then,
$$P = C^2_5 P(A)^2 (1-P(A))^3$$

But I don't quite understand the solution. I think it is wrong because it takes in consideration the case ( + + - - 0) while the final gain will be 0 points. Am I wrong?

Comment: Maybe the "winning 40 points" translates to: having exactly twice event $A$, regardless of the other attempts, as long as they are not $A$. So, having a sequence of $ABABB$ it's "winning 40 and losing 60", and not just "netting -20". Other than that, it looks to me that your approach is correct.

Comment: @nicola so the formulation of the question is wrong.

Comment: I agree with you. I was just trying to "reverse engineer" the meaning given their solution.

Comment: The problem is very vague.  Reading it, I would guess that the writer means "find the probability that, at the end of round $5$, the player has at least $40$ points." but that's not consistent with their answer.  It seems bizarre to say that three losses followed by two wins (for a net loss of $20$) somehow corresponds to "winning $40$ points" but that's implied by their answer.  Certainly wouldn't have guessed that.

Comment: Linguistically, it seems that it makes a distinction between **winning** $40$ points, and winning **by** $40$ points, but it does make the question rather obscure !